# is it possible to limit texture resolution by distance?

Tags: rendering, performance, memory-management

I know in the simplify tab you can set a reduced texture size for all of the scene, but is it possible to reduce the texture size in vram based on distance from the camera?

For example I have a 2km stretch of land I'm modelling for a client animation, at one end of the landscape there's a stone wall with an 8k texture, and at the other end there's a wooden bridge with an 8k texture.  In between there are other objects with large textures also.  Most of them are in view from a distance and close up, so do need to keep the high res textures rather than simplifying the entire scene's texture sizes.

Cheers
Michael.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98365/texture-blurry-when-viewed-at-shallow-angle/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86214/scaling-texture-based-on-distance-to-camera